# PHP - XPATH select elements containing ONLY white-spaces or nothing

Tags: php, xpath, whitespace, domxpath

how do I select a `<td> </td>` that is empty or ONLY contains white spaces no matter how many with XPATH in PHP?

I'd like to replace the two `not(text())` in the code underneath in order to not only match no text but also white spaces.

`//tr[td[1][contains(text(), "'. $match .'")]] 
    /following-sibling::tr[td[1][not(text())] and preceding-sibling::tr[1][td[1][not(text()) or contains(text(), "'. $match .'")]]]`

Comment: http://codepad.org/ALBcpGew

Comment: replacing it for `not(text())`in the example underneath gives me an error…

`//tr[td[1][contains(text(), "'. $match .'")]]
     /following-sibling::tr[td[1][not(text())] and preceding-sibling::tr[1][td[1][not(text()) or contains(text(), "'. $match .'")]]]
`

Comment: you are aware that your example is quite different from "selecting only nodes with whitespace", are you?

Comment: You are right! I never said "selecting only whitespaces"! I want to select the ones containing nothing or whitespaces but noText. UPDATED the question to make things more clearly! So this is definitely not a duplicate of the question you linked to mine… I already came across that one and it didn't help me solving the problem. Therefore I'm asking to remove the link please.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The linked dupe answers "how do I select a <td> </td> that is empty or ONLY contains white spaces". The linked codepad example shows that it does. Consider providing a sample XML and the nodes you want to match from it. Consider http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist